# Colocar galeria com texto

Tags: android, xml

Estou tentando colocar uma galeria de produtos no meu app, e queria a imagem e o texto em baixo, estou usando o viewpager, porem o texto ta ficando do lado, e as imagens muito longe uma da outra, so ta aparecendo uma imagen queria que aparecesse pelo menos 2 com o texto em baixo.
Vejam os codigos:

ViewPagerMain

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Item

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ranklabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ranklabel" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rank"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ranklabel" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/countrylabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ranklabel"
    android:text="@string/countrylabel" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/country"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rank"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/countrylabel" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/populationlabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/countrylabel"
    android:text="@string/populationlabel" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/population"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/country"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/populationlabel" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/flag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:padding="1dp" />
```

Como colocar as imagens mais proximas e o texto em baixo?

Comment: Pessoal, como uso a função "Executar trecho do Código" ao perguntar?

Comment: @WarLock existe uma sample app que exemplifica muito bem o que você quer, pelo menos é o que eu acho veja e me diga se é isso mesmo? https://github.com/googlesamples/android-XYZTouristAttractions faça o download e crie seu app

Answer (score 1):

Bem...A sua pergunta está muito vaga, mas ao apresentar somente o código XML, posso responder que há somente um `<ImageView` , ou seja, SOMENTE UMA IMAGEM. Adicione mais um `<ImageView` ao seu xml e para que os textos fiquem abaixo, em forma de coluna, retire os `android:layout_toRightOf`, dos `<TextView` ponha algo parecido com isto:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/flag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:padding="1dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/flag2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:padding="1dp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ranklabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ranklabel" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rank"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/countrylabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ranklabel"
    android:text="@string/countrylabel" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/country"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rank" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/populationlabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/countrylabel"
    android:text="@string/populationlabel" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/population"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/country" />
```

**LEMBRANDO que é necessário, também, adicionar mais códigos Java para essa nova ImageView. Não adianta somente adicionar essa ImageView no XML.**

Comment: Pessoal, como uso a função "Executar trecho do Código" ao perguntar?